# Can't handdle FCM notification when app in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Guys even tho I wrote the code to handle the foreground I only recive notifications only when the app in the background I don't know what is the problem hope you can help me with this I'm really stuck

This is my FirebaseMessagingService class code :

```
 private static final String CHANNEL_ID ="101" ;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, All_Tickets.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "101")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the method "onNewIntent" of your main activity (activity which is set as main in your Manifest). It can be called with your push in foreground. If it called you must get data from your intent's extras.